# Al iniciar signalR en 2 o mas pestañas diferentes los servicios desplegados con net core dejan de funcionar

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, signalr

Al iniciar signalR en 2 o mas pestañas diferentes los servicios desplegados con net core dejan de funcionar deja de funcionar todos los servicios que tengo levantados se tiran y no se puede consumir ninguno

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que estas utilizando?
tanto la configuración de Signal R como en el Jaascript o el metodo con el que lo consume?

Comment: Hola Favio, Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar). Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!